# Select not null values in a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table like below:

```
ID  Value1  Value2  Value3
1   abc      null    null
1   null     def     null
1   null     null    ghi
```

I want to select only the not null values that too in single row, i.e. the output should be as below:

```
ID  Value1  Value2  Value3
1   abc     def     ghi
```

Is it possible to achieve the same using sql?

Comment: Is there exactly one non-null value in each column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select id, 
max(value1) as value1,
max(value2) as value2,
max(value3) as value3
from table
group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID,
    MAX(Value1) AS Value1,
    MAX(Value2) AS Value2,
    MAX(Value3) AS Value3
FROM your_table
GROUP BY ID
```

**[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/372039)**